# Colors are not populating/applied in the list view - OOTB Calendar List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-calendar

Here is my link for default calendar page where i created a calendar list.

`http://srvr1:28516/Lists/myCalendar/calendar.aspx` and in this page, colors been applied based on category

then i added a  lstview of this,

```
   [![calendar1][1]][1]
```

the issue am facing is,  am not able to get the colored way of displaying the categories in this listview. How to achieve this? 
 am adding the listview in the home page and am not able to see the calendar with color-coded way.

Below is the calendar listview web part i have added and facing the issue of color-less categories.Will the  calendar overlay , work for me, in this case?

```
    [![calendar-without-colors][1]][1]
```